# Decreasing integral sequence

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, sequences-and-series, analysis

How does one show that $I_n = \int\limits_0^1 x^n e^x dx$ is decreasing?

The best I came up with is this: $I_{n-1} - I_n= \int\limits_0^1 e^xx^{n-1}(1-x)dx$, but how do we go from here?

I'd appreciate some hints.

Comment: Well, the integrand is nonnegative, so you have what you want

Comment: @AhmedHussein But how to show it rigorously that it's non-negative?

Comment: Just note that $0 \le x \le 1$ gives $0 \le 1 - x$, and that $e^x$ is always $\ge 0$e

Comment: @AhmedHussein can you show this as one inequality? Otherwise, it doesn't appear to be quite rigorous.

Comment: I have no idea what rigour you are talking about. This is evident.

Comment: Since we're on $x \in [0, 1]$, we can use that $x^{n + 1} \leq x^n$.

Comment: Do you need to prove that $e^x$ is non-negative, that $x^n$ is non-negative, or that the product of two non-negative functions is non-negative?

Comment: It is called Mean Value Theorem ... https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mean_value_theorem#Mean_Value_Theorems_for_Definite_Integrals

Comment: So, is it sufficient to just argue that because the integrand is $>0$ then the integral from $0$ to $1$ must be $\ge 0$?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You may prove much more than monotonicity: since $e^x$ is bounded between $1$ and $e$ on $[0,1]$,

$$ \int_{0}^{1} x^n(1-x)\,dx\leq \int_{0}^{1}e^x x^n(1-x)\,dx \leq e\int_{0}^{1} x^n(1-x)\,dx \tag{1}$$
hence:

> $$ \frac{1}{(n+1)(n+2)}\leq \left(I_n-I_{n+1}\right)\leq\frac{e}{(n+1)(n+2)}.\tag{2} $$

The inequality in the RHS of $(2)$ is tighter since $g(x)=(n+1)(n+2)x^n(1-x)\mathbb{1}_{(0,1)}(x)$ is the PDF of a random variable that converges towards $X=1$.

Answer (score 1):

According to [Mean Value Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mean_value_theorem#Mean_Value_Theorems_for_Definite_Integrals), there $\exists c \in (0,1)$ such that 
$$\int_{0}^{1}e^xx^{n-1}(1-x)dx=e^cc^{n-1}(1-c)(1-0)\geq0$$

because $f(x)=e^xx^{n-1}(1-x)$ is continuous on $[0,1]$

Comment: How do you justify that $\exists c \in (0,1)$?

Comment: I don't have to, Mean Value Theorem (MVT) does that for me. $f(x)=e^xx^{n-1}(1-x)$ is continuous on $[0,1]$. MVT is a really well known theorem.

Comment: I calculated $f'(c) = e^c[(n-1)(c^{n-2}-c^{n-1})-c^n]$. By the MVT, we know that $|f(1)-f(0)| = f'(c)$ for some $c\in [0,1]$. But how do we go from here?

Comment: There is a MVT for derivative and MVT for integration. Both called MVT. See the link in my answer ;)

Comment: OK, the MTV for integrals. Very nice solution too.

Comment: Yep, this MTV "saved" my life many times ;)